# Special switch or out of box failure?

Tags: router

I just bought my very first router, it's a DeWalt DW621 (it has a cord, no batteries). I plugged it in and pressed the on-switch, but I'm getting no response from the router.

Did I forget to remove some safety pin, or is this likely an out of box failure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that specific router, but the [instruction manual](https://servicenet.dewalt.com/documents/English/Instruction%20Manual/N384544,DW621.pdf#_ga=2.59523885.1608888850.1535398345-56622243.1535398345) (page 9) indicates it has a lock-on/lock-off safety feature:

> **Lock-On/Lock-Off Switch (Fig. 7)**
>   The lock-on/lock-off 
>   switch is located in the
>   handle on the right side.
>   The router is normally
>   locked-off.
>   To start the router, press
>   the thumb lock and
>   squeeze the trigger.
>   To lock the switch on,
>   squeeze the trigger,
>   press the thumb lock
>   forward and release the
>   trigger. To turn the router
>   off, release the switch. If the tool is locked-on, press the trigger
>   again and release the switch.

Make sure you press that thumb lock switch when squeezing the trigger.

Comment: This was exactly the issue, I figured it out a few minutes ago before seeing your answer. I feel like an idiot -_-

Comment: @Cloud9999Strife Glad it works! Feel free to vote up the answer if it helped, and mark it as accepted if the solution worked for you.

Comment: @Cloud9999Strife, don't feel bad, you're not the first person to make a mistake like this and you won't be the last :-)